# How to store a password in encrypted form in Craft CMS?

Tags: encryption, yii

I'm very new to Craft, and Craft's fairly new to the world. I'm wondering if anyone knows how to encrypt a password for storage with in the database, or can point me in the right direction where there's some instructions on how to do this?

I've had a good search around and not come up with anything. I've read the docs, which does have an encrypt method in its 'Security Service', but I don't understand how to implement it. I've also come across a plugin that might help; https://github.com/t3kila/SecureField-Craft but I'd prefer a native solution so that the storage remains non-dependent on any third party plugins.

I’ve tried;

```
$password = craft()->securityService->encrypt($password)
```

but to no avail… I’m sure it’ll be a fairly simple exercise for someone who knows how , but it’s just so new that there isn’t a lot of information out there.

Comment: Before I answer, can you please explain why you want to encrypt passwords [rather than store them properly](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016)?

Answer (score 2):

This should be fairly straightforward. You can use Craft's [SecurityService](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/SecurityService) but you should also `base64_encode` your encrypted password before storing in the database.

```
$encryptedPassword = base64_encode(craft()->security->encrypt($password));

$decryptedPassword = craft()->security->decrypt(base64_decode($encryptedPassword));
```